# Symfony2: choice without empty value

Tags: symfony

It seems to be easy but I cannot succeed into doing it. I have choices element. I want them to display only the value I set and not the default value (or empty value).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 45):

To disable empty value, try this:

```
$builder->add('states', 'choice', array(
    'empty_value' => false,
));
```

If you leave the empty_value option unset, then a blank (with no text) option will automatically be added if and only if the required option is false.

For **Symfony 2.6+** please use 'placeholder' => false option to avoid empty value.

```
$builder->add('states', 'choice', array(
    'placeholder' => false,
));
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder

Comment: It seems that this option doesn't exist anymore in symfony 3... How can I get the same result ? Thanks...

Comment: Ok, I got it, use `'placeholder' => false`

Comment: Just want translate "None" option in radio in symfony 3.2 `'placeholder'=> 'your none option'`